# Which image was selected in a 2 column UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I just started with Iphone development and would like to know the following.

I have a UITableView setup with 2 columns each cell has an image. When the user clicks a cell I want to push another view and display a large image of the one that was clicked.

Under the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath, allows me to push a new view however with 2 columns in one row not sure how to determine which image was click.

Thanks
Elias

Answer (score 1):

didSelectRowAtIndexPath works for the whole row only. What you can do is make your column cells or your images into a UIButton so you can handle the events on them separately.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making Buttons (as recommend by [tsakoyan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729091/which-image-was-selected-in-a-2-column-uitableview/5729210#5729210)), you could add [GestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html) to your column views.

Comment: Thanks i'll look into adding GestureRecognizer.

Comment: Yes, indeed simpler solution, it avoids the view restructuring of my method!